# Bash: Loop a file until it reaches specific number of matching strings and start over

Tags: linux, string, awk, sed, grep

Edit: Long story short: I'm trying to count the amount of successful connections from a log file. If it reaches 8, I need it run some command, then start over and count again.

I try to loop through a file, and grep for a specific string, and count the lines of it with wc -l. If it reaches 8 I need it to run a command, then start again from that point.
Assuming I have a file like the example below:
I want to find "STRING" and if wc -l is equal to 8 I need to run a command and start over (append something and start from there) and count the other 8 that comes after them.

```
STRING ...................
STRING ...................
STRING ...................
STRING ...................
STRING ...................
STRING ...................
...
```

I wrote this:

```
while true
do
countz=$(cat file.txt | grep "STRING" | wc -l)

echo $countz;

if [ "$countz" -eq 8 ];
        then #do_something
fi
done
```

Comment: So what's the question? It might be helpful to know more about what the _something_ is that you're trying to do. Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: I'm trying to count the amount of successful connections from a log file. If it reaches 8, I need it run some command, then start over and count again.

Comment: Unless your input file REALLY just has the word "STRING" repeated multiple times and everything else is chains of "..."s, [edit] your question to contain truly representative, concise, testable sample input and expected output. Don't show us the word "STRING", show us examples of the types of strings your file contains and what you want to find. Consider partial matches, regexp metacharacters, word delimiters, etc. Replace the `...`s with actual text. The less effort you put into asking the question the less likely you are to get a robust solution.

Answer (score 3):

Not very clear what you want to achieve but

```
seq 100 | xargs -n 1 echo STRING \
| awk 'BEGIN { c=0; } $0 ~ /^STRING / {c++; if (c==8) { print "found"; c=0; } }' \
| your_command
```

This will execute your_command for every 8-th line

Or maybe you can count the total number of occurences of STRING in a file and dived it by 8 and then run that number of commands ?

```
countz=(cat file.txt | grep "STRING" | wc -l)
total_runs=$[countz / 8]
for ((i=0;i<$total_runs;i++)); do your_command; done
```

**UPDATE**
Seems you want to edit log file.
Easiest will be to create a new file with "delimiters"

```
awk 'BEGIN { c=0; } {
    print $0;
    if ($0 ~ /^STRING /) {
        c++;
        if (c==8) { print "your delimiter"; c=0; }
    }
 }' logfile > processed_logfile
```

Comment: It is a log file, if the number of successful messages reaches 8, I need to set a "breakpoint" and count the next 8 over and over again. Doing "your_command" every time it reaches 8

Comment: Just like setting a delimiter for every 8 occurrence. not lines.

Answer (score 1):

It's still not completely clear what you're trying to do so I'm guessing a bit but you can probably do something like this:

```
awk '(c += /STRING/) == 8 { system("some command here"); c = 0 }' file
```

This adds to the counter `c` whenever the pattern matches and then runs a command every time the counter reaches 8.

If instead of running some command, you want to print some additional output, the script can be modified slightly:

```
awk '1; (c += /STRING/) == 8 { print "8 matches since last time"; c = 0 }' file
```

The `1` is the shortest *true* condition to trigger a `{ print }`, so every line is printed. After every 8 matches, the message is also printed.